# Which compiler is currently used in android to compile Java to .class files after D8 dexer was introduced?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compilation, android-d8

After Jack compiler was deprecated and D8 was introduced where the java -> .class files part was separated again (unlike jack where it happened in a single step), is the Oracle Java SE `javac` compiler being used for compilation again?

Comment: Yes, it's javac

Answer (score -1):

ART(android runtime) is used now replacing delvik

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime

Comment: The question is not about the runtime environment.